# How to define a recursive trait bound in Rust?

Tags: rust, traits, trait-objects

First, I know I can use `Box` if I want to define a recursive structure. For example,

```
struct LinkNode {
    next: Option<Box<LinkNode>>
}

impl LinkNode{
    fn get_next(&self) -> Option<Box<LinkNode>>{
        None
    }
    fn append_next(&mut self, next: LinkNode) -> Self{
        self
    }
}
```

But **how can I make a trait on these structures via templates or trait object**?
Due to the existence of `fn append_next(...) -> Self`, I cannot create a trait object directly like this:

```
pub trait Linkable {
    fn get_next(&self) -> Option<Box<dyn Linkable>>; 
    fn append_next(&mut self, next: impl Linkable) -> Self;
}
```

And we cannot return `Option<Box<impl Linkable>>` or `impl Linkable` for `fn get_next(&self)`.

Then I tried the following implementation via generic templates and it does not work.
Because I need to assign the type of `T` recursively when construct a new `LinkNode`.

```
pub trait Linkable<T:Linkable<T> + Clone> : Clone {
    fn get_next(&self) -> Option<Box<T>>;
    fn append_next(&mut self, next: T) -> Self;
}
```

---

I finally implement it in this way, by creating other traits for assistance. And it works well. Again...Is there other better ways?

```
pub trait Linkable: LinkClone{
    fn get_next(&self) -> Option<Box<dyn Linkable>>;
}

pub trait LinkAppend {
    fn append_next(&mut self, next: Box<dyn Linkable>) -> Box<dyn Linkable>;
}
pub trait LinkClone{
    fn clone_box(&self) -> Box<dyn Linkable>;
}

impl<T> LinkClonefor T
where
    T: 'static + Linkable+ LinkAppend + Clone,
{
    fn clone_box(&self) -> Box<dyn Linkable> {
        Box::new(self.clone())
    }
}

impl Clone for Box<dyn Linkable> {
    fn clone(&self) -> Box<dyn Linkable> {
        self.clone_box()
    }
}
```

**BTW, I have some other questions during the exploration above: Why Rust forbids the `impl Linkable` sugar, like the `Box<impl Linkale>`? And why returning `impl Linkable` is forbidden in a trait?**

---

**Updated** after *Ibraheem*'s answer:

Except the associated type implementation from *Ibraheem*, it is also fine to work like this. The core idea is to avoid the recursive type declaration in the trait.

```
pub trait Linkable {
    fn get_next<T:Linkable>(&self) -> Next<T>; 
    fn append_next<T:Linkable>(&mut self, next: Next<T>) -> Self;
}

struct Next<T: Linkable> {
    node: T,
}
```

This is mentioned in another [question: Can I define a trait with a type parameter of itself in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62905847/can-i-define-a-trait-with-a-type-parameter-of-itself-in-rust?rq=1)

Comment: One other option worth considering is an associated type to the trait. Depending on how you use it, that may be preferable.

Comment: @user1937198 Thanks. It's a great idea. I thought it a more efficient way to use associate type or generics during compiling. Is the cost of trait object huge? I know it is implemented via dynamic dispatch, which works like virtual methods in c++.

Comment: depends on your definition of huge. The major cost is inlining, and then the dynamic dispatch. Its worth knowing the dyn pointers are twice the size, but other than that its not really any different from c++/

Comment: The cost depends on what you are doing. For some things, it is noise. For others, it is prohibitive. In general, it is best to avoid dynamic dispatch unless your design really calls for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Linkable` could have associated type called `Next`.

```rust
pub trait Linkable {
    type Next: Linkable;
}
```

`get_next` now returns an instance of type `Self::Next`, and `append_next` takes `Self::Next` as a parameter:

```rust
pub trait Linkable {
    type Next: Linkable;
    
    fn get_next(&self) -> Option<Self::Next>;
    fn append_next(&mut self, next: Self::Next) -> &Self;
}
```

Now you can implement `Linkable` for `Linknode`:

```rust
impl Linkable for LinkNode {
    type Next = LinkNode;
    
    fn get_next(&self) -> Option<Box<LinkNode>> { 
        None
    }
    fn append_next(&mut self, next: LinkNode) -> &Self {
        self
    }
}
```

> Why Rust forbids the impl Linkable sugar, like the Box? And why returning impl Linkable is forbidden in a trait?

You can refer to *[Is it possible to use `impl Trait` as a function's return type in a trait definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39482131/is-it-possible-to-use-impl-trait-as-a-functions-return-type-in-a-trait-defini)* for the answer to this question.